# Separate the .txt file contents to multiple cells in .csv file

Tags: python, csv, parsing, text

I'm using Python 2.7, i have got a txt file like this which one i'm opening it with python :

```
TIME    FLIGHT  FROM    AIRLINE AIRCRAFT        STATUS
8:40 AM LH1334  
Frankfurt (FRA)
Lufthansa   A320 (D-AIPP)   
Landed 8:40 AM
8:45 AM OK786   
Prague (PRG)
Czech Airlines  AT45 (OK-KFP)   
Landed 8:32 AM
```

I want to export it to csv in the correct mode to 6 columns (Time, Flight, From, Airline, Aircraft, Status), i want to get this:

```
TIME            FLIGHT  FROM            AIRLINE         AIRCRAFT      STATUS
Jul 21 8:40 AM  LH1334  Frankfurt (FRA) Lufthansa   A320 (D-AIPP) Landed 8:40 AM
...
```

Its a little bit hard for me, because in a row there are multiple words, so i haven't got any useful idea, how i can reach this form.

My code:

```
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

f = open('proba.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

maindatatable = to_2d(x, 6)
print maindatatable
output.writerows(x)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Anyway, what you showed in example isn't exactly CSV (and is more similar to TSV).

Comment: Sorry, i updated my question with my code!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they're grouped as 4 lines each.

We can process the first line

```
8:40 AM LH1334
```

<s>as follows:</s>

```
import re

matches = re.match('(\d{1,2}:\d{2} [APM]{2}) (\w+\d+)', line)
time = matches.group(1)
flight = matches.group(2)
```

**EDIT:** This bit is overkill. There is a tab separating them, so it's actually very easy:

```
time, flight = line.split('\t')
```

The second line:

```
Frankfurt (FRA)
```

Is trivial:

```
from_ = line
```

The third line:

```
Lufthansa   A320 (D-AIPP)
```

can be processed:

```
airline, aircraft = line.split('\t')
```

And the fourth line:

```
Landed 8:40 AM
```

is also trivial:

```
status = line
```

---

Altogether, you can process them in batches of four lines each:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('my.txt') as f:
    header = f.readline()  # skip header

    while True:
        # read four lines
        lines = list(islice(f, 4))
        if len(lines) < 4:
            break

        time, flight = lines[0].split('\t')
        from_ = lines[1]
        airline, aircraft = lines[2].split('\t')
        status = lines[3]

        # Output a row into your csv file here
```

Comment: I updated the question with my code, can you check it?

Comment: Isn't working… **how?** Do you get an error message? If so, show it. If not, what are the results and what's wrong with them? "not working" doesn't help much to diagnose the problem.