# How to delete the first X and the last X rows in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, text

I want to delete the last 16 and the first 16 lines in a csv file using Pyton 2.7.

what am i wrong in my code? Why not delete these rows?

```
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

f = open('air.txt', 'r')
x = f.readlines()

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

maindatatable = to_2d(x, 4)
print maindatatable
output.writerows(maindatatable)

with open('output.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    lines = csvfile.readlines()
    lines = lines[16:-16]
    cWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in lines:
        cWriter.writerow(line)
 resultcsv.close()
```

Sorry if this seems like a really simple question, but I'm new to python and any help in this area would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: This looks like a way overcomplicated approach to solving something very simple. What does the `air.txt` contain and what's your end goal?

Comment: here you can see, what cointains the air.txt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231230/separate-the-txt-file-contents-to-multiple-cells-in-csv-file/45231512#45231512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is this line:

```
cWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

The file has already been opened in read mode. You cannot initialise a csv writer on this file (it is not open for writing).

To fix, you can declare another `with` block and set up another context manager.

```
with open('output.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    lines = csvfile.readlines()
    cReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    lines = cReader.readlines()[16:-16]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    cWriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    cWriter.writerows(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is using pandas. Read the .csv file into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
```

Then remove the first 16 rows:

```
df.drop(df.head(16).index, inplace=True)
```

and the last 16 rows:

```
df.drop(df.tail(16).index, inplace=True)
```

then save the .csv back to file:

```
df.to_csv('output_out.csv')
```

Comment: I get a very long error message and i can opening the csv file only "reading" mode

Comment: that sounds weird, you can check options to read csv files with pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)